# Move row up and reset index pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns. need to sortby tr_date and move the 6th index row to 1st index.

```
original datafarame

index tr_date      val_date    des         con    cr   dr  bal
0      05-06-2020   05-06-2020  JH876875    NEFT    0   500 500
1      02-07-2020   02-07-2020  45546       MPS    100  0   400
2      02-07-2020   02-07-2020  45546       IMPS    20  0   380
3      22-07-2020   20-07-2020  AASADD      with    200 0   -320
4      28-07-2020   15-07-2020  876876      withdr  0   300 -20
5      03-08-2020   01-08-2020  BCGFD       NEFT    200 0   -220
6      02-07-2020   02-09-2020  23          man     500 0   -120

Expected output:

index tr_date       val_date    des         con    cr   dr  bal
0     05-06-2020    05-06-2020  JH876875    NEFT    0   500 500
1     02-07-2020    02-09-2020  23          man     500 0   -120
2     02-07-2020    02-07-2020  45546       MPS    100  0   400
3     02-07-2020    02-07-2020  45546       IMPS    20  0   380
4     22-07-2020    20-07-2020  AASADD      with    200 0   -320
5     28-07-2020    15-07-2020  876876      withdr  0   300 -20
6     03-08-2020    01-08-2020  BCGFD       NEFT    200 0   -220
```

Comment: What rule does it follow ? Is it sorting by tr_date (ascending order) and then by val_date (descending order) ?

Comment: @vincent sorting by tr_date only (ascending order) .

Comment: Yes but moving the 6th row to the 1st row ? Why ? Based on how you build your dataframe, the specific row you want to put in 1st position will not always be in 6th position. This is why I suggest dealing with the problem with a rule, like "the row I want in 1st position is the row with XXX condition".

Comment: the row I want in 1st position is the row with cr !=0

Comment: In that case I suggest not following the answers below but instead look for "How to put a row in first position based on column value" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

this code works for changing the rows:

```
df.iloc[6], df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[1], df.iloc[6]
```

greetings Jan

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df=df.sort_values(by='tr_date').reset_index()
```

If you want to secondarily sort on other columns, just add them on by parameter (eg `by=['tr_date', 'des']`)